# bevel modifier does not seem to work

Tags: modeling

i am a new user to blender and I was watching a tutorial and then I hit a problem that the bevel modifier did not seem to work, I think it might be but it was not showing the same results in the tutorial if you can help me I will really appreciate it.
here is a link
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5wA96GZr/
please tell me if the link does not work

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so there seems to be a few things going on here. Firstly, and I don't know if this is intentional, but your single mesh object is comprised of 2 different pieces sitting on top of one another:

[image: Pieces1]

As you can see from the image, both of the pieces seem to have some parts that don't belong. I separated the pieces only for this example image, you don't have to do it yourself, unless you want to delete a piece or something. If you need to separate them, select a face and press <kbd>L</kbd>. This will select everything that is part of the same "piece". You can then move it away, or whatever.

You can get rid of the stuff that doesn't belong (pieces separated or not) by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> (Merge) and selecting "By Distance". This removes duplicated or overlapping vertices. Doing this to yours removed 24 vertices - you can see the count in the bottom right corner when you perform the operation.

[image: Merge]

Lastly the bevel is still a bit off as the result of non-uniform scale (result of scaling in object mode). To fix this, in object mode, select your object, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select "Scale".

[image: Scale]

Comment: thank you for the help

Comment: A link to the tutorial (assuming it's in English) would be useful.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxpjudV_88&t=1091s

Comment: Ok. I've just looked at that part of the tutorial and followed it exactly. Creating the gear by following the tutorial does NOT produce that internal structure that Christopher mentions above and both the subsurface and bevel modifiers work correctly so I'd suggest you delete the gear completely and and start again from scratch.

Comment: yeah i think that i accidently duplicated it before extruding